# two "in"s in a row

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

> 1. There is only one blank to fill in in that sentence.
> 2. There is only one blank to fill in that sentence.

Grammatically speaking, both "in"s are needed, because of "fill in the blank" and "in that sentence."  But I want to know if people would prefer to use sentence (2) by virtue of (1) being redundant.

Comment: 'blank' and 'black' are not the same word.

Comment: Thanks   I will add a correction.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is not really correct; it is possible either to "fill in" a blank or to "fill" a blank. (You can go to Google Books and search for a phrase such as "fill all of the blanks". You should get quite a few hits that don't use "in".) Therefore, both of your sentences are correct.

That being said, in my experience it is more common to "fill in" a blank. Therefore, the first sentence would be more usual, despite the consecutive instances of "in".